# Vue js populate new selects when changing the main one

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need your help about populating or loading new select with vue js, I know how to do this with jquery but in vue i don't know how because i'm new with this library.

i have the main select :

```
<select>
   <option value='3'>FRANCE</option>
   <option value='5'>USA</option>
   <option value='6'>CANADA</option>
   <option value='8'>MOROCCO</option>
</select>
```

I want that if i choose FRANCE i get a select of FRANCE cities from database, and also when i select USA i get an other select of USA cities from database.

So for example i will get :

```
<select>
   <option value='6'>CANADA</option>
   <option value='8'>MOROCCO</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value='34'>France city one</option>
   <option value='35'>France city two</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value='3'>Usa city one</option>
   <option value='5'>Usa city two</option>
</select>
```

When choosing France and USA i will populate select of cities with an array

I appreciate any help, I don't realy know how can i do this with vue js, 
I don't want add all select of cities in my html because i don't know how much countries i have.

I tried this but this not resolve my probleme :

```
const addProduct = new Vue({
el: '#addProduct',
data: {
    name: '',
    name_url: '',
    cities: '',
    countries: [],
    range: 0
},
created: function () {
    this.$http.get('/api/countries').then(response => {
        this.countries = response.data
    }, response => {

    });
},
methods: {
    addForm: function(val, data) {
        this.range += 1;
        alert(this.range)

        var index = _.findIndex(this.countries,{city_id: val});
        this.countries.splice(index, 1)
    }
},
watch: {
    'cities' (val, oldVal) {
        this.$http.post('/api/cities/values', {city_id:val}).then(response => {
            this.addForm(val, response.data);
        }, response => {

        });
    }
}
```

});

in html :

```
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-4">
        <label for="attribute">Countries</label>
        <md-select name="country" id="country" v-model="country">
            <md-option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.country_id">@{{ country.name }}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <my-cities v-for="n in range"></my-cities>
</div>

<script type="x-template" id="my-cities">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-4">
        <label for="attr">Cities</label>
        <md-select name="attr" id="attr" v-model="attr">
            <md-option value="">Select </md-option>
            <md-option value="val in values">Select</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </div>
</script>
```

an example like this on Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pu8pp62v/3/

Comment: Any help.......?

Comment: your code is unrelated to your task. Clarify please: what response do you get from database, how do you request data. What data do you want to receive from db into your Vue app in order to manipulate.

Comment: Okay i will edit the question now for more explanations

Comment: it's done now, Can you re check the question please?

Comment: Up Up Up Up Up Up I realy need help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that you can maybe use (but need some modifications to use your API call) :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
   return {
     selectedCountries: [],
     selectOptionsCountries: [
       { value: 3, name: 'FRANCE' },
        { value: 5, name: 'USA' },
        { value: 6, name: 'CANADA' },
        { value: 8, name: 'MOROCCO' }
      ],
      selectedCities: [],
      selectOptionsCities: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
   
  },
  watch: {
    selectedCountries: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.selectOptionsCities = [];
      this.selectedCities = [];
  
      for( var i = 0, length = newValue.length; i < length; i++ ){
      
        this.selectedCities[i] = [];
        
       if( newValue[i] === 3 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 31, name: 'Paris' },
            { value: 32, name: 'Marseille' }]
          )
        }
        if( newValue[i] === 5 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 51, name: 'New-York' },
            { value: 52, name: 'Boston' }]
          )
        }
        if( newValue[i] === 6 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 61, name: 'Montreal' },
            { value: 62, name: 'Vancouver' },
            { value: 63, name: 'Ottawa' },
            { value: 64, name: 'Toronto' }]
          )
        }
        if( newValue[i] === 8 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 81, name: 'Rabat' },
            { value: 82, name: 'Casablanca' },
            { value: 83, name: 'Fes' }]
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  Selected countries : {{ selectedCountries }}
  <br />
  Selected cities : {{ selectedCities }}
  <br />
  <select v-model="selectedCountries" multiple>
     <option v-for="(option, index) in selectOptionsCountries" :value='option.value'>
       {{ option.name }}
     </option>
  </select>
  
  <select v-for="(optionsCities, index) in selectOptionsCities" v-model="selectedCities[index]" multiple>
    <option v-for="(option, index) in optionsCities" :value='option.value'>
       {{ option.name }}
     </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But what i want is when selecting france and after that selecting usa i want that france select still in dom, So when selecting france and after selecting usa i want have in total 3 select one for countries and the second for france cities and the last one for usa cities

Comment: @Codinga you can select FRANCE and USA at the same time in my example. Strange UX behavior to have to select FRANCE, then USA to select cities of FR and USA. So if you mistake and click on FRANCE but you don't want FRANCE cities what is the way to remove FRANCE cities ?

Comment: I can't do this after with vue js? if i want remove for example the dropdown of France cities ?

Comment: In your example you push cities in the same dropdown? What i need is create an other dropdown each country with his onw dropdown? For example if i have 7 countries and i select all of them i will have in my html country dropdown and 7 other dropdowns (cities dropdowns)

Comment: @Codinga Ok I updated my code : select all Countries to see the result. Use [Ctrl] to select or deselect a country

Comment: Great, Tnx so much for the replay, But here you set conditions, i get countries from database so i can't know how much countries i have

Comment: @Codinga I said this is an example. We can't do everything for you :) Now you can use this code and add your API. The logic is here so you have some work to do :)

Comment: @Codinga but you can do an API call in created function : `created: function() { this.selectOptionsCountries = responseOfApi; }`

Comment: yes yes of course already done. i create a function in methods that can do all this jobs, i just want to see if what i do t-is the good practice, i'm returning to you once i finish this. Thank Youuu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140090/discussion-between-slycee-and-codinga).

Answer (score 0):

**Added after author's comment:**

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjpfvx5q/1/

Inside 'chosenCities' array you have all selected cities by country (one city per country.)

**Original answer:**

Here is an example for you: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfnm218h/1/)

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

setTimeout functions are just pretending a real data fetching.

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
<div>
  <select v-model="country">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option
      v-for="c in countries"
      :value="c.id">{{ c.name }}</option>
  </select>
<span>Selected: {{ country }}</span>
<span  v-if="cities.length">Cities:</span>
<ul v-if="cities.length">
<li v-for="c in cities">{{ c }}</li>  
</ul>
</div>
</template>
</div>

<script>
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        country: {},
        countries: [],
        cities: [],
        coInit: [{ id: '3', name: 'France' }, { id: '2', name: 'USA' }], 
        cFrance: ['Paris', 'Whatever'], 
        cUSA: ['NY', 'LA'] 
      }
    },
    methods: {
        loadCountries: function () {
        setTimeout(() => { this.countries = this.coInit }, 500);
      },
      getCities: function() { 
      if(this.country) {
        switch (this.country) {
            case '3': 
            setTimeout(() => { this.cities = this.cFrance }, 500);
            break;
          case '2': 
            setTimeout(() => { this.cities = this.cUSA }, 500);
            break;
        }
      }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadCountries(); 
    },
    watch: {
        country: function() { 
        this.getCities();
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main);
new Ctor().$mount('#app');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But what i want is when selecting france and after that selecting usa i want that france select still in dom, So when selecting france and after selecting usa i want have in total 3 select one for countries and the second for france cities and the last one for usa cities

Comment: also i can't use switch in getCities because i don't know how much countries i have so the probleme is that i need something dynamic

Comment: @Codinga , switch is just for example purpose, of course. getCities() is where you need to fetch cities based on 'country' (which is country id)