# Populate new inputs on dropdown select with Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need help on populating some input fields on a form with Vue 3. When a user selects an option in my dropdown the form should output the necessary inputs. Instead it will show all inputs from every option.

Here is my select dropdown

```html
<select
 v-model="selectedInverter"
 @change="onChange($event)" >
   <option
     v-for="(item, index) in options"
     :value="item.inverter"
     :key="index" >
       {{ item.inverter }}
   </option>
</select>
```

And here are my options

```js
export default {
  name: "ExampleOptions",
  data() {
    return {
      address: "",
      stakeAddress: "",
      selectedInverter: null,
      addressError: "",
      apiKey: null,
      filteredOptions: "",
      options: [
        {
          inverter: "None",
          options: []
        },
        {
          inverter: "Eagle",
          options: [
            {
              name: "Cloud ID",
              value: null,
              description:
                "The Rainforest cloud id used to access your system data",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            },
            {
              name: "User",
              value: null,
              description: "The Rainforest cloud username",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            },
            {
              name: "Password",
              value: null,
              description: "The Rainforest cloud password",
              type: "password",
              required: true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          inverter: "Efergy",
          options: [
            {
              name: "Token",
              value: null,
              description: "The Efergy token used to access your system data",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            },
            {
              name: "Power",
              value: null,
              description:
                "The Efergy power key, usually 'PWER' or 'PWER.1234' where 1234 is the sid",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
```

And this is my codepen example: https://codepen.io/pistell/pen/BaJPjgq

As you can see all the dropdown examples are shown at all times. How can I get the ones selected in the dropdown to show? I'm also using Tailwind CSS if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      address: "",
      stakeAddress: "",
      selectedInverter: null,
      addressError: "",
      apiKey: null,
      filteredOptions: "",
      // TODO: Create a way to iterate over these values and populate the HTML elements that go along with each of these
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250578/vue-js-populate-new-selects-when-changing-the-main-one
      options: [
        {
          inverter: "None",
          options: []
        },
        {
          inverter: "Eagle",
          options: [
            {
              name: "Cloud ID",
              value: null,
              description:
                "The Rainforest cloud id used to access your system data",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            },
            {
              name: "User",
              value: null,
              description: "The Rainforest cloud username",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            },
            {
              name: "Password",
              value: null,
              description: "The Rainforest cloud password",
              type: "password",
              required: true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          inverter: "Efergy",
          options: [
            {
              name: "Token",
              value: null,
              description: "The Efergy token used to access your system data",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            },
            {
              name: "Power",
              value: null,
              description:
                "The Efergy power key, usually 'PWER' or 'PWER.1234' where 1234 is the sid",
              type: "text",
              required: true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    computed_items() {
      const selected = this.selectedInverter;
      return this.options.filter((item) =>  item.inverter.includes(selected));
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async registerInverter() {
      this.addressError = this.address.length > 1 ? "" : "Not a valid address";
      if (!this.addressError) {
        await this.validateAddress();
        // Values to send to Firebase
        console.log({
          address: this.address,
          api_key: this.apiKey,
          date_registered: new Date().toUTCString(),
          inverter: this.selectedInverter,
          stake_address: this.stakeAddress
        });
      }
    },
    async validateAddress() {
      // Evaluate the address and check if its valid
      console.log(this.address);
      return this.address;
    },
    onChange(event) {
      this.selectedInverter = event.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
    <div class="w-full max-w-md">
      <form
        class="bg-white shadow-lg rounded px-12 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4"
        @submit.prevent="registerInverter"
      >
        <!-- @csrf -->
        <div
          class="text-gray-800 text-2xl flex justify-center border-b-2 py-2 mb-4"
        >
          Register your Inverter
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label
            class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-normal mb-2"
            for="address"
          >
            Wallet Address
          </label>
          <input
            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            name="address"
            v-model="address"
            type="text"
            required
            autofocus
            placeholder="Input your address"
          />
          <div v-if="addressError" class="error">{{ addressError }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-normal" for="inverter">
            Inverter Model
          </label>
          <div class="inline-block relative w-full py-4 flex-1">
            <select
              class="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              v-model="selectedInverter"
              @change="onChange($event)"
            >
              <option
                v-for="(item, index) in options"
                :value="item.inverter"
                :key="index"
              >
                {{ item.inverter }}
              </option>
            </select>
            <div
              class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 text-gray-700"
            >
              <svg
                class="fill-current h-4 w-4"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                width="20px"
              >
                <path
                  d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">

          <div
            v-for="(item, index) in computed_items"
            :value="item.inverter"
            :key="index"
          >
            <h2>{{ item.inverter }}</h2>
            <div
              v-for="(item, index) in item.options"
              :value="item.name"
              :key="index"
            >
              <input
                class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline mt-1 mb-1"
                :name="item.name"
                :type="item.type"
                :required="item.required"
                :placeholder="item.description"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="registerButton">
          <button
            class="px-4 py-2 rounded text-white inline-block shadow-lg bg-blue-500 hover:bg-green-500 focus:bg-blue-700"
            type="submit"
          >
            Register
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```